# Why won't the "div" expand with the content inside it?

Tags: html, css

I added a DIV called "midsection" inside the body. It contains all of the content like the slideshow and the information below it. I set the midsection height to "98%" but it will not expand with the content inside of it. The actual page does expand but the DIV does not.

-HTML
   http://e.pictureupload.us/118270967451ca3420af8dd.jpg

-CSS

```
#midsection{
position:relative;
top:31px;
width:75%;
height:98%;
margin-left:12.4%;
background:#f3f4f4;
border-left: 1px black solid;
border-right: 1px black solid;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code here.  It will be a lot easier to help you...

Comment: I added it as a picture.

Comment: Why would you add the code as an image? Please copy/paste it into your question.

Comment: I did, but it automatically un-indented it and I could not send it as a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding overflow:auto to the div:

```
#midsection
{
  ...
  overflow:auto
}
```

Comment: Not my favorite, but it works. I still would like the actual page to expand.

Comment: @AdamDePolo, If this worked for you then you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check symbol.

Comment: I was still waiting, if you read my response, you can see I said "I still would like the page to expand"....

Answer (score 1):

A div has an inherent maximum height of it's container. You would have to make sure every item in the DOM containing this div has a height of at least 98%. For instance, if the div was just in the body, you can add:

```
html{ min-height:98%; }
body{ min-height:98%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the CSS for the div.